# I need something similar to sleep function for a program that uses OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing a game (Othello) on C++ using OpenGL graphics, and I need something to "wait" or "sleep" the game after the user places a piece. The CPU plays too fast right after the user plays, so is not possible to see user's move. I tried with sleep function but it's not working. Basically, the idea is:

Player inserts new piece
----sleep for 1 second----
CPU inserts a new piece

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In C++11 you can do `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1))`

Comment: "I tried with sleep function but it's not working." You should probably find out exactly why that doesn't work. Just trying alternatives at random is not a generally effective method of problem solving. But once you figure that out I would definitely recommend `std::this_thread::sleep_for` for all your sleeping needs. For running a game at a particular speed there are other possibilities such as using a real scheduler for game updates.

Comment: @Rapptz: If you call that from the main thread, it will suspend the main loop which can cause visual glitches (as it won't redraw).

Comment: @DietrichEpp That sucks.

Comment: Hard to provide specific solutions without any code.

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: timer function is not provided by opengl and if you use c++ sleep function doesn't solve your problem. Which library you are using to create window? If you are using glut or GLFW for creating windows then these library provide timer function to render the scene within required interval of time.

Comment: @Dinesh I'm using glut, do you mean I can call to a different function, instead of glutCreateWindow()?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are just learning programming. And you are discovering an important step.

The first code people write is most likely on the console, and it is serial: Write a question, wait for input, do something. Print output. That is perfectly fine and many programs work like this.

Unfortunately GUIs do not. They have roughly three independent parts:

- The computer working (like in your game the AI)
- The player doing something, like clicking on the board to make a move
- Showing on the screen what is currently going on

Now all of those things can happen while one of the other is going on. Some need to wait for each other. But they basically could happen in random order. Chaos! What if the player clicks while the AI is still thinking? Maybe the board needs to be redrawn because the OS moved the window.

You did not say what OS you are working on, but OpenGL should always only do number 3. Showing exactly the board as it is. If you want to make the computer slower it should be in point 1.

The classic way to solve this is a message loop and queue.

If you first program looks like this:

```
while ( gamenotdecided )
    ask human to enter move (wait for it)
    update board (and show it)
    compute AI move
    update board (and show it)
do
```

The new way is more like this:

```
while ( gamenotdecided )
    get the next message:
        if it is show board: show board;
        if it is input: if it is not the humans turn print an error. 
                        else make it, and send yourself a message to show the board and start AI
        if it is AI: Do a small part of AI thinking. 
                     Send yourself a message to keep doing AI if there is no good move yet. 
                     If the AI is decided:
                         if enough time passed
                              make the move, send yourself a message to show the board
                         else 
                              wait a tiny bit and send yourself a message to do AI again 
do
```

The part of the AI thinking is where you can wait for time, if the AI is too fast. The key is that you can show the board at any time, no matter if it is the user or the AI turn. 
All GUI OSes also have a way to send a message only after a certain amount of time. But even without that you can easily do it: If you get an AI message, the AI knows what to do, but it's not time yet, just don't do anything and send yourself another AI message. Your idea was to delay drawing the board. But what you really want to do is to delay the AI making it's move. It is a subtle but very important difference.

It is important to keep in mind that the board and it's "state" are always around. But any of the messages can happen at any time: If the user clicks while the AI is thinking? No problem, the board tells you whose turn it is. If you need to draw the window because it got moved? No problem, the board is right there, no matter whose turn it is. The AI is too quick? No problem, just keep spinning for a while before updating the board. The AI is too slow? No problem, let it think for a bit, send a show board and AI again.

I hope this explains a bit the concept you should look at. Sleep or Threads have nothing to do with it yet. They are optimizations. One way people approach this is called MVC, Model, View, Controller. In this case the Model would be the board state, including whose turn it is. The view is you GL code. And both the player and the AI are Controllers.

But first, if you take one thing away from this: GUIs are not sequential. Anything can happen at any time. Message queues are a simple way to deal with this.

I am a bit curious which language and OS you are using, I probably can give better examples if I know that. Do you use any framework for OpenGL?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not just learning programming, but I'm pretty new with OpenGL staff, sorry about that. I'm using C++ and Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

C++11 provides [`this_thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) as part of the thread support library.
If you don't have access to C++11, you could try the [POSIX Threads libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)